# Intermittent (each startup) Wi-Fi with an Edimax EW-7318USg

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb

Firstly, Wi-Fi works 100% of the time on my Ubuntu netbook, my Android phone and my Windows install (on the same computer/USB-wifi device), so I don't think this can be a router issue... It would be strange if it were a driver issue as it sometimes connects, but FYI the USB-wifi device is a Edimax EW-7318USg.

Second, if it does connect (during this session) then it connects first time, else it will not connect (no matter how long I try). Wi-Fi does connect about 20% of the time (restarting the computer about 5 times usually allows me to connect). Once it has connected it stays connected (until restarted).

Obviously it is hugely irritating! Any ideas how I can remedy this?

EDIT: As requested, the results of running `sudo lshw -class Network`:

```
description: Ethernet interface
       product: MCP77 Ethernet
       vendor: nVidia Corporation
       physical id: a
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0a.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: a2
       serial: 00:19:66:d3:fe:21
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm msi ht bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=forcedeth driverversion=0.64 latency=0 link=no maxlatency=20 mingnt=1 multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:41 memory:fcf7c000-fcf7cfff ioport:c880(size=8) memory:fcf7e400-fcf7e4ff memory:fcf7e000-fcf7e00f
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 00:0e:2e:4d:ff:b4
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt73usb driverversion=2.6.38-8-generic firmware=1.7 ip=192.168.2.6 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
```

*Is this a known bug or should it be filed as one? (if so, which or against what?).*

Comment: google didnt bring up any hits for that model - are you sure if it is correct?  Please add to your question the results of sudo lshw -class Network

Comment: My mistake, I misread the S for an 8, it's actually an EW7318USg. Thanks!

Comment: @fossfreedom I have corrected the device name in the question, and inserted the results of sudo lshw -class Network. Many thanks.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

Find out if any log entries are helpful - I usually do:

`touch $HOME/now`

Record the time right now.
Then, make the event happen (or, wait until the event happens, doing periodic `touch $HOME/now`s.

Then, after the event has happened, do `find /var/log -cnewer $HOME/now` to get a list of the log files that were changed between the most recent `touch $HOME/now` and the `find` command. Look at the last N lines of each.